# Stackdriver alert policy not triggering

Tags: gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a custom logs based metric, based on logs emitted by my application, like this:

```
resource.type="k8s_container" resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster" resource.labels.namespace_name="preprod" resource.labels.container_name="my-app" jsonPayload.logType="MyEventType"
```

I wanted to setup a custom alerting policy based on it and make it trigger an alert if there's no logs for 10mins.

I did something like the following:

```
{
  "combiner": "OR",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "conditionAbsent": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_SUM"
          }
        ],
        "duration": "600s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/my-metric-preprod\" resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
        "trigger": {
          "percent": 100
        }
      },
      "displayName": "No log events for 10 mins"
    }
  ],
  "displayName": "My custom policy - preprod",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": // doesn't matter
}
```

Although everything looks fine, when I stop emitting events, nothing is executed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated this with the same values in your JSON;

```
   {
  "combiner": "OR",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "conditionAbsent": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "60s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_SUM"
          }
        ],
        "duration": "180s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/test-alerting\" resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
        "trigger": {
          "percent": 100
        }
      },
      "displayName": "logging/user/test-alerting"
    }
  ],
  "displayName": "testing",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": [
    "NOTIFICATION/CHANNEL/123"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Not sure why you're alerting is not working, have you verified the notification Channel?

Comment: I thought you're summing over a alignmentPeriod, are you sure it a sum of all-time data?

Comment: `Align time series via aggregation. The resulting data point in the alignment period is the sum of all data points in the period. This alignment is valid for gauge and delta metrics with numeric and distribution values. The value type of the output is the same as the value type of the input.` - here the alignmentPeriod is 60s, so I assume it takes a sliding window of 60s.

Comment: I've replicated this with the same configuration and the notifications are working.

Comment: When you read metric data using the Metrics Explorer or the Monitoring API, you can use aggregation to summarize the time series data. Aggregation typically starts with an** alignment step in which each time series' data is placed on the same time boundaries**. Next, a new time series is created by combining the data points from multiple time series, using operations like average, sum, minimum, maximum, and so forth.  See: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#aligning & https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#aligner